# Kill skeleton horses with command block in a radius

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am an admin on a Minecraft server and I am trying to figure out how to kill skeleton horses in a certain radius using command blocks.

Since 1.11 our old function has stopped work, partly to do with the skeleton horses singular entity tag.

The command blocks I have set are 2 separate ones set to repeat

The code I have currently is:

Add to scoreboard command block:

```
scoreboard players tag @e[type=EntityHorse] add skeleHorse {Type:4}
```

Kill command block:

```
minecraft:kill  @e[tag=skeleHorse,r=250]
```

What I have tried is as follows:

Add to scoreboard command block:

```
scoreboard players tag @e[type=skeleton_horse] add skeleHorse
```

Kill command block:

```
minecraft:kill  @e[tag=skeleHorse,r=250]
```

Comment: `/minecraft:kill` isn't a valid command in vanilla; are you using some server software that allows this command? You should be able to simplify it down to `/kill @e[type=skeleton_horse,r=250]` rather than adding a tag first. Are the tags being added correctly? Are the command blocks activating? What error message are you getting?

Comment: The horse is getting added to the scoreboard, no errors. I get the following error in my kill cmd: [15:03:49] Entity '@e[type=skeleton_horse,' cannot be found

Comment: By the time (`[15:03:49]`), it looks like that command block isn't being activated. If you put `/say test` into it, is chat spammed with "test"?

Comment: Yes that works, already checked that the blocks were responding :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use this in a command block:

```
minecraft:kill @e[type=skeleton_horse,r=50]
```

You don't even need the first command block for adding them to the scoreboard anymore.

Answer (score -1):

I finally solved it!

So this is what I ended up with:

Scoreboard Command Block:

```
scoreboard players tag @e[type=skeleton_horse] add skeleton_horse
```

Kill Command Block:

```
minecraft:kill @e[type=skeleton_horse,r=50]
```

This now works and those pesky horses die on spawning.

Comment: you do realise that you don't even need the first commandblock, right?